# Error:(18, 56) error: cannot find symbol variable webView

Tags: android, android-webview

I get this error **Error:(18, 56) error: cannot find symbol variable webView**

Here is code of `Activity`

```
package com.example.luke.sinhalasindu;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class Ruwan_Hettiaracchi extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ruwan__hettiaracchi);

        String url = "http://mfi.re/listen/lwmzyjsdmnri868/Ruwan_Hettiarachchi_Duka_Wadi_Nethe.mp3";
        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_ruwan__hettiaracchi, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.luke.sinhalasindu.Ruwan_Hettiaracchi">

    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post `activity_ruwan__hettiaracchi` layout

Comment: remove `this.` from this line `WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);`

Comment: Error:(18, 51) error: cannot find symbol variable webView

Comment: @badde If u want help. Show your logcat and layout file

Comment: @badde is that full layout ?

Answer (score 2):

From your layout

```
WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

should be

```
WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

Answer (score 2):

add `android:id="@+id/webView"` on activity_main.xml

Answer (score 1):

Id was mismatching

Change your layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.luke.sinhalasindu.Ruwan_Hettiaracchi" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In java initialize `WebView` variable like this

```
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```