# Error: "error:cannot resolve symbol 'WebViewClient'

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

I already tried referring both to this [StackOverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652943/error18-56-error-cannot-find-symbol-variable-webview) as well as this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYdLVehpd48) but still have not found a solution to my problem.

I set permissions already in the Android Manifest XML file, and have my webview problem under the FullscreenActivity file. My code is here:

```
       @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
    WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    view.loadUrl("platinumskincare.com");
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    mVisible = true;
    mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
```

The error I keep getting says 'Cannot Resolve Symbol 'WebViewClient', and I believe it is on line 44 of my code. What should I do and how do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

- **Check if you have these imported**

> import android.webkit.WebView;
>
> import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

- **Clean and rebuild your project in Android Studio.**